# Find the latest occurrence of an class item and store how many values are between these two in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with some labels for `n` classes. Now I want to add a column and store how many items are between two elements of the same class.

```
   Class
0      0
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      0
```

and I want to get this:

```
    Class  Shift
0      0    NaN
1      1    NaN
2      1    1.0
3      1    1.0
4      0    4.0
```

This is the code I used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class':[0,1,1,1,0]})
df['Shift'] = np.nan
for item in df.Class.unique():
    _df = df[df['Class'] == item]
    _df = _df.reset_index().rename({'index':'idx'}, axis=1)
    df.loc[_df.idx, 'Shift'] = _df['idx'].diff().values
df
```

This seems circuitous to me. Is there a more elegant way of producing this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df['shift'] = np.arange(len(df))
df['shift'] = df.groupby('Class')['shift'].diff()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Class  shift
0      0    NaN
1      1    NaN
2      1    1.0
3      1    1.0
4      0    4.0
```

As an alternative:

```
df['shift'] = df.assign(shift=np.arange(len(df))).groupby('Class')['shift'].diff()
```

The idea is to create a column with consecutive values, group by the *Class* column and compute the [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) on the new column.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont see your answer, so posted same, sorry. So removed after I realised it.

Comment: @jezrael It was I did not see your answer, but I think our answers are complementary

Answer (score 1):

If there is default RangeIndex use [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) with grouping by column `df['Class']` and [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['Shift'] = df.index.to_series().groupby(df['Class']).diff()
```

Similar alternative is create helper column:

```
df['Shift'] = df.assign(tmp = df.index).groupby('Class')['tmp'].diff()

print (df)
   Class  Shift
0      0    NaN
1      1    NaN
2      1    1.0
3      1    1.0
4      0    4.0
```

Your solution with reseting index should be simplify by:

```
df['Shift'] = df.reset_index().groupby('Class')['index'].diff().to_numpy()
```